# Inconsistent node spacing in TikZ positioning (MWE)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following MWE which I would like to produce one top node and then 2 chains of children nodes, roughly like:

```
     top

a1         b1

a2         b2

a3         b3
```

but instead, I get more something like this:

```
     top

a1         b1
a2           
a3         b2

           b3
```

[image: PDF produced]

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={
            text width=.2\linewidth,
            draw,
        },
    ]
    \node(top){top};

    \node(a1)[below left=of top]{a1};
    \node(a2)[below of=a1]{a2};
    \node(a3)[below of=a2]{a3};

    \node(b1)[below right=of top]{b1};
    \node(b2)[below=of b1]{b2};
    \node(b3)[below=of b2]{b3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is that correct and I am just missing something in my understanding, or is it a problem in TikZ? Is there a workaround? I am using TexLive as packaged in Ubuntu 22.04 (version 2021.20220204-1).

Comment: In your example you mixe syntax of pure Ti*k*Z and of  `positioning` library. Use just one of them, since they are differ on way of node positioning, i.e.: between center of nodes at `[below of=a1` and between nodes' borders at `below=of b17` ).

Comment: Oh, cool! I typed it twice and thought I typed the same. Making it all `below of=` makes the layout consistent now. Can you write that as an answer so that I can accept it? I appreciate that you helped me so swiftly.

Comment: `right of` is [considered deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386/16595) and `right=of` should be used. The option `on grid` can be used to place the nodes in relation their centers again (instead of the borders which is the default of `positioning`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me extend my comment to an answer ...

- In your example you mix syntax for determining nodes position of pure Ti*k*Z (`below of=a1`)  and of `positioning` library (`below=of b1`).
- The first is deprecated and determine distance between center of nodes, the second determine distance between borderders of nodes.
- In cases when you for some reasons like to position nodes in respect to their centers, than you should use option `on grid` (as noted @Qrrbrbirlbel in his comment) in the image preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance =7mm and 3mm,
every node/.style={draw, text width=0.2\linewidth},
    ]
\node(top){top};

\node(a1)[below left=of top]    {a1};
\node(a2)[below=of a1]          {a2};
\node(a3)[below=of a2]          {a3};

\node(b1)[below right=of top]   {b1};
\node(b2)[below=of b1]          {b2};
\node(b3)[below=of b2]          {b3};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\vskip 7ex 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0.1\linewidth and 0.25\linewidth,   % <--- observe that nodes distance is changed 
on grid,                        % <---
every node/.style={draw=red, text width=0.2\linewidth},
    ]
\node(top){wirh option \verb+on grid+};

\node(a1)[below left=of top]    {a1};
\node(a2)[below=of a1]          {a2};
\node(a3)[below=of a2]          {a3};

\node(b1)[below right=of top]   {b1};
\node(b2)[below=of b1]          {b2};
\node(b3)[below=of b2]          {b3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]